# Can I change state in 100 components in one click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have 100 Post components on one page. Each has state `isActive`. I have also on this page seperate list with only titles of these posts. If I click on the item in list, then I would like to change state of Post Component to isActive: true, and in rest components to isActive: false.

I have Posts component over Post components, so I should in Posts component iterate through all Post components and set change state to isActive:false without current clicked Post component?

Is not that exaggerating in this case? Is it efficient? I use Redux, so maybe it will help somehow?

```
class Posts extends Component {
  state = { 
    isActive: this.props.isActive
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, index) => 
          <Post isActive={this.state.isActive} key={index} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts.posts,
    isActive: state.posts.isActive
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Posts);

class Post extends Component {
  state = { 
    isActive: this.props.isActive
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isActive: !state.isActive
    }));
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className={this.state.isActive ? "show" : ""} onClick={this.onClick}>
        Post
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;

class List extends Component {

  onClick = () => {
    //here I would like to set isActive:true to current clicked Post and isActive:false to rest of Posts
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, index) => 
          <li onClick={this.onClick}>{post.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts.posts
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(List);
```

Comment: If you weren't using Redux, I would suggest keeping this `isActive` state in the parent component. But, you are using Redux. So why don't you change the state in your store somehow? How is your store's and related state's shape? If you share that information it would be good.

Comment: Assuming that all of this components are beeing rendered based on a parent state you just have to change the state on the parent

Comment: So first I have to change all components to isActive:false and next current Post to isActive:true?

Comment: Logically, yes. This can be done easily if your state is structured good enough. This is why I'm asking the related code. Though, this can change according to how and where you use this piece of state. For example, those inactive posts will be visible somewhere else? Do you want to change set `isActive` to `true` by clicking those posts again? So, we can't exactly suggest anything if we can't see some code and your app structure.

Comment: @devserkan I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You are mixing your state with Redux and React's local one. Sometimes you can do that as in a form but in your situation, I think it is not practical and not the right way. Why? You have already a global `posts` state, then why you move this state into the local one? As you can see things get difficult if you do that. Try to keep this `isActive` state in your global state, then you have one single point to check the state and use it anywhere.

Comment: Also, you don't need to set your props to your state as you do in `Posts` component. You don't need a local state there either. If you have props via Redux, then use it directly, don't set it again to your local state. One more thing, you don't need to pass `null` in place of `mapDispatchToProps`, you can skip it. This applies to `mapStateToProps` only if you don't use it.

Comment: How to set this state globally on isActive: false for all Post components, but only for one Post (clicked from list) on isActive: true?

Comment: There isn't any single answer for that :) You can keep this `isActive` property in each post item, then with an action creator, you can update all the posts' state. Or, you can have a `status` property in your state, then you can add and remove each post's id to this array or object then check the status again by looking this. Since you are not using this logic now, we can't directly answer anything. I or somebody else would write an app as a quick one, but If you want to learn React and Redux, you need to code it. I'm saying this as a learner :)

Comment: Thanks, please add new answer.

Comment: Do you mean a simple app by saying "answer" :) You can find a short answer provided by @xadm more or less what I tried to explain here. It just shows how you can use a property, but creating an action creator and updating your state again is your responsibility :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple app just in one file :) You can read the comments and try to understand what is going on. It will give you an idea of how you can keep a `status` state in your store, dispatch an action and update your state.

As you will see, `Post` and `List` components does not have any state. They are just dumb components. The parent one, `Posts` component renders them.

You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j101v839y), fork and play it. There are separate directories and files for this example. I just put everything in one file to move it here properly. I can't promise to keep the sandbox too long, so you may want to fork it immediately :)

PS: This is a midnight fun. It may include not the best practices :)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";

// To use styles in a single file. You can use a .css file to define those
// and use className instead of styles in the Post component

const styles = {
  post: { border: "1px solid gray", marginTop: "-1px" },
  show: { backgroundColor: "silver"}, 
}

// Posts is the parent component. It renders Post and List component by
// mapping the posts.

class Posts extends React.Component {
  // This method changes the status state by passing a post to
  // the action creator

  handleStatus = post => this.props.changeStatus(post);

  // This method maps the posts and renders Post components for each post.
  // We are passing the post and isActive boolean.

  getPosts() {
    return this.props.posts.map(post => {
      // We are getting the isActive by checking the status state
      // if it has our post's id.
      const isActive = this.props.status[post.id];
      return <Post key={post.id} post={post} isActive={isActive} />;
    });
  }

  // This method renders our List items, li's. Again, we are passing the
  // post and our handleStatus method to change the status.

  getList() {
    return this.props.posts.map(post => (
      <List key={post.id} post={post} handleStatus={this.handleStatus} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.getPosts()}
        <ul>{this.getList()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Post is a stateless, dumb component. It just renders the post item.

const Post = props => {
  const { id, title } = props.post;
  const { isActive } = props;

  // We check the isActive and if it is true then add a show class.

  let classes = styles.post;
  if (isActive) {
    classes = { ...classes, ...styles.show };
  }

  return (
    <div style={classes}>
      <p>ID: {id} </p>
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// List is a stateless, dumb component just renders li's. But, it has
// handleStatus prop. By onClick and using another method, we are
// passing our post back to the parent, to the handleStatus method

const List = props => {
  const { post, handleStatus } = props;
  const changeStatus = () => handleStatus(post);
  return <li onClick={changeStatus}>{post.title}</li>;
};

// We open our state to our component.

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.posts.posts,
  status: state.posts.status,
});

// This is our action creator, takes the post as parameter and
// use it as the payload.

const changeStatus = post => ({
  type: types.CHANGE_STATUS,
  post,
});

// Connecting our component.

const ConnectedPosts = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { changeStatus },
)(Posts);

// Just defining our action creator types, avoiding magic strings.   

const types = {
  CHANGE_STATUS: "CHANGE_STATUS",
};

// This is our reducer. We have one posts property and one status in our state.

const initialState = {
  posts: [
    { id: "1", title: "foo" },
    { id: "2", title: "bar" },
    { id: "3", title: "baz" },
  ],
  status: {},
};

// Our reducer takes the post and adds post's id in our status state.
// In the initial state they are all undefined, so not true. In the first
// click, we change to true for each post. If we click again, we change it to
// false without mutating our original state.

const posts = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CHANGE_STATUS: {
      const {
        post: { id },
      } = action;
      const newStatus = { ...state.status, [id]: !state.status[id] };
      return { ...state, status: newStatus };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// Our store.    

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

// Rendering our app.

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedPosts />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement,
);
```

Comment: This reducer will allow to `open` many posts and `close` all of them - when click on already active item. `const newStatus = { {}, [id]: true };` - will give you an "accordion style" - allow `open` and `change` (closing the rest) but no `close`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just store selectedID (or index) and use simple condition, sth like this:

```
class Posts extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, index) => 
          <Post isActive={this.props.selectedIDX === index} post={post} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}    

// connect with posts and selectedIDX 


class List extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler = (id) => {
    this.props.actionToSetSelectedIDX( id );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, index) => 
          <li onClick={(e, index) => this.onClickHandler(index) }>{post.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }

 // connect with posts, selectedIDX and actionToSetSelectedIDX
```